# Browser Cached image is not update for me if i append time at the end of Image url

Tags: jquery, image, browser-cache

Please help me I have image update issue just because of browser cache.

Here is my code not working for me:
`$("#artist-icon-box img").attr('src', artist_icon_src+'?vr='+Math.random());`

Here artist icon src content image path value from database.

```
artist_icon_src = /ws/ABC/artist/download/id/9/field/icon/last_updated/1400513937
```

if i open this url in another browser tab then it open actual image that i want but not load in application.
 i try :

```
localhost/ws/ABC/artist/download/id/9/field/icon/last_updated/1400513937
```

then it display actual image.

In this code i try both time stamp and also Math.random() and it return different value each time but it does not pick up image from server.

Comment: Are you seeing the image at all (just a cached version) or are you getting an error when loading it?

Comment: Yes,  I see the image but that is of cached version not the updated one

Comment: Can you provide the URL for your page so I can try and see what's going on?

Comment: hi svpino and Thanks for your response,

Comment: I found solution when i upload image that time i rename image file name with time stamp,so browser doesn't look in cache it take new copy from server now it's working successfully for me.

Comment: I have another Question if you know please help me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077520/how-to-fix-ldap-error-cant-contact-ldap-server-getting-in-ckan-default-error